# Google maps control panel disappears?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I have 2 problems with the code below and I’ll post them separately.  I have reduced the code down to a reasonable size for this forum hopefully.  The problem here is that when I first go to the page (or reload the page) and click the go button the map initializes and the control panel is displayed at the top centre.  When I click the go button again the control panel disappears.  Why?  It needs to remain as I have a selection menu containing addresses and lat/lon’s which will ultimately drive this map and I don’t want to refresh the page all the time.

Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var lat = -31.953;
var lon = 115.853;
var address = "200 St George's Terrace, Perth, WA, 6000";

function initialize() {

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
                var addrLatLon = results[0].geometry.location;

                var mapOptions = {
                    center: addrLatLon,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

                bounds.extend(addrLatLon);
                var addrMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: addrLatLon,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Address Location',
                    draggable: true
                });

                if (lat != 0 && lon != 0) {
                    var LatLon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
                    bounds.extend(LatLon);
                    var latlonMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: LatLon,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'Lat/Lon Location'
                    });
                }

                map.fitBounds(bounds);

                // Place control div
                var control = document.getElementById('map-control');
                control.style.display = 'block';
                map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(control);

                // Update current position info.
                updateMarkerPosition(addrLatLon);

                // Add dragging event listener.
                google.maps.event.addListener(addrMarker, 'drag', function() {
                    updateMarkerPosition(addrMarker.getPosition());
                });

                // Check zoom and set accordingly
                google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
                    if (map.getZoom() > 16) map.setZoom(16);
                });

            } else {
                alert('No result found for address.');
            }
        } else {
            alert('Geocoder failed: ' + status);
        }
    });
}

function updateMarkerPosition(p) {
    document.getElementById('map-control').innerHTML = [
        p.lat(),
        p.lng()
    ].join(', ');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mapchk").click(function() {
        initialize();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-control" style="border:thin solid #000;"></div>
<div id="map-canvas" style="position:absolute;top:80px;left:30px;height:500px;width:600px;border:thin solid #000;"></div>
<input type="submit" name="mapchk" id="mapchk" value="Go"  />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click 'go' first time, #map-control element is moved from its original location and appended inside the #map-canvas element.
When you click 'go' next time, the map is redrawn. So #map-control is not in the dom anymore. So your map.controls.push does not do anything.

You can try making a clone of the #map-control element and then push it into map.controls.